# wsdl2java generate java classes with longnames

Tags: java, maven, package, wsdl2java

i am wondering, how can i generate java classes like belows with maven wsdl2java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MGTSInstantRequest")
public class MGTSInstantRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Input", required = true)
    protected com.ank.mgtsinstant.mgtsinstantwsdl.Input input;
```

instead of this -->

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "MGTSInstantRequest")
public class MGTSInstantRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Input", required = true)
    protected Input input;
```

i dont want to add extraargs because i must not change namespace/packagename, it is using in another java project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to have full packagename into your generated java classes.

Have you tried **packageSpace** option as parameter of the maven [axistools:wsdl2java](https://www.mojohaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/wsdl2java-mojo.html#packageSpace)  plugin to set up fullpackage name ?